# the distribution of $\frac{(X_1 +X_2)^2}{(X_1 -X_2)^2}$

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random sample of size $2$ from a $N(0, 1)$ population, then the distribution of $\frac{(X_1 +X_2)^2}{(X_1 -X_2)^2}$

My work: I find the expectation of $E(X_1 +X_2)^2 = E(X_1 -X_2)^2 =2$, but after that how do I proceed?

Comment: How is your "work" supposed to help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are indepedent
$$
X_1+X_2\sim N(0,2);\quad X_1-X_2\sim N(0,2)
$$
where the second parameter is variance. We may write $X_1+X_2\stackrel{d}{=}\sqrt{2}X_1$ and $X_1+X_2\stackrel{d}{=}\sqrt{2}X_2$. Hence
$$
\frac{(X_1 +X_2)^2}{(X_1 -X_2)^2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{X_1^2}{X_2^2}\sim F(1,1)
$$
because $X_1^2\perp X_2^2$ and $X_1^2\sim \chi^2_{(1)}$.

Note $\stackrel{d}{=}$ means equal in distribution.

Comment: You didn't mention that $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are also independent. Without that, your argument is incomplete.